# Buildroot: qt application with an empty install target

Tags: qt, qmake, buildroot

I am integrating my own Qt app into buildroot. *.mk file follows.

```
CATCHER_SITE=http://g7/gitlab/igorsk/catcher.git
CATCHER_SITE_METHOD=git
CATCHER_VERSION=master

CATCHER_DEPENDENCIES=qt

ifeq ($(BR2_PACKAGE_QT5),y)
CATCHER_QMAKE = $(QT5_QMAKE)
else
CATCHER_QMAKE = $(QT_QMAKE)
endif

define CATCHER_CONFIGURE_CMDS
    (cd $(@D); $(TARGET_MAKE_ENV) $(CATCHER_QMAKE))
endef

define CATCHER_BUILD_CMDS
    $(TARGET_MAKE_ENV) $(MAKE) -C $(@D)
endef

define CATCHER_INSTALL_TARGET_CMDS
    $(TARGET_MAKE_ENV) $(MAKE) INSTALL_ROOT=$(TARGET_DIR) -C $(@D) install
endef

$(eval $(generic-package))
```

The app compiles, but it doesn't get installed to a target directory (and therefore to resulting rootfs ). During buildroot's "Installing to target" phase I get `Nothing to be done for 'install'.` message. `buildroot/output/build/catcher-master/Makefile` has emtpy `install` rule.

Buildroot 2015.08.1
Qt 4.8.7

The question is: why is this happening and how do I get my app installed to target?

Comment: I suspect that there's something wrong with your .pro file. Does the install target work for a native build? If not, please edit your question, remove all Buildroot references and ask it for qmake. Or abandon this question and ask a new one.

Comment: @Arnout You're right. Some digging revealed, that there has to be a properly set `INSTALLS` variable in `*.pro` file for non-empty `install` target to be generated by `qmake`. Qt-Creator leaves this to programmer.

Comment: @IgorS.K. have you already used CMake? It has many nice features like CPack (package creation: tar, deb, rpm etc.) and is also good integrated into Buildroot.